# How to transfer SUM value to another page (getting error =SUM(#REF!) )

Tags: excel, vba

In this instance I'm using `Range("a5")` to `SUM` cells a1:a3. Once the SUM is completed I want to run the VBA and then paste the `SUM` result from  `sheet1`  onto `sheet2`

If a number is typed directly in `Range("a5")` things work fine.

I've been working with `PasteSpecial`, to date I have had no success with this.

I would have thought that `value` or `value2` would have accomplished this goal, but that has not been the case so far. I have a feeling I am missing something fairly simply with this.

```
Sub TransferSum()

    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a5")

    Rng.Copy

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a1")

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula refers to cells above its location but there are no cells above A1, hence the error. Plus, your syntax was off.

If you just want to transfer the value ...

```
Sub TransferSum()

    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a5")

    Rng.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a1").pastespecial xlvalues
    'OR IN ONE LINE
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a1").value=rng.value 'or Value2

End Sub
```

Comment: Great, I was hoping to keep this to one line.   If you have time I'm not sure what you mean by  'Your formula refers to cells above its location but there are no cells above A1' Does this mean the way things are currently written the paste would go above A1? I thought default with past is always down the spreadsheet.

Comment: Your original formula was in A5 but referenced cells above it (A1:A3). When you move to another location, the relative references will be maintained, but there are no cells above A1. You can test this yourself manually on a worksheet formula.